# How did I manage to store a reference type in a standard container?

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, copy-constructor

While trying to work with C++11 smart pointers and container classes, I've written two pieces of code which basically boil down to the following:

```
class Foo { ... };
typedef std::unique_ptr<Foo> FooPtr;

// First attempt; this did _not_ compile
typedef std::unordered_map<int, FooPtr> IntToFooMap;

// Second attempt; this _did_ compile
typedef std::unordered_map<int, const FooPtr &> IntToFooMap;

// here is the declaration causing the error in the second case:
IntToFooMap m {
    { 41, FooPtr(new Foo()) }
};
```

As you can see, first I tried to define an unordered map of `FooPtr`, which didn't compile, because `FooPtr` is an `std::unique_ptr` which is not copiable (it has a deleted copy constructor).

More precisely, it is the initialization of the map using an initializer list that caused the error.

To my great surprise, however, the second version, whereby I defined the `value_type` of the unordered map as a **const reference to `FooPtr`, did compile.**

Up until today, I thought that it is not possible in general to store values of reference type in standard containers. While this behavior is somewhat intuitively understandable, since declaring a (const) reference prevents the -- otherwise prohibited -- copying of the `unique_ptr`, I still don't fully understand how or why this works. ***If it works at all,*** of course; I would not be surprised if this was just a subtle corner case that resulted in undefined behavior.

Comment: Note that non-copy-constuctable doesn't necessarily mean a type can't be stored in a container. Now that C++11 has move semantics, the standard containers can store movable but non-copyable types.

Comment: `typedef std::unordered_map<int, FooPtr> IntToFooMap;` compiles fine on g++ 4.8.2

Comment: @Slava For the record, I am using clang 3.4.

Comment: @user3477950 [Can't](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0d340acb5ba535dd) [reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c740217b48962356) either.

Comment: @T.C. Indeed, when I've compiled [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3f3b3383154ad6d0), it did now compile.

Comment: @user3477950 on clang 3.4 typedef with unique_ptr fails to compile or some operations on the map?

Comment: @Slava It is the initialization of the map object (using an initializer list) that fails. [Here is the beginning of the error message](http://pastebin.com/zaXQgF5p), in case you are interested.

Comment: @user3477950 Your second case results in a dangling reference. [Note how](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9144bbd6639b5687) in this case the `Foo` was destroyed before control reaches the next statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You violated a constraint of the library. This results in undefined behavior. The library may or may not detect that it's a reference.

The problem with references is that the library is allowed to presume that the container owns the object which holds the value of the element, and therefore to call its destructor, in particular it can do this:

```
allocator_traits<A>::destroy(m, p) // m is the allocator, p points to object.
```

I didn't notice language explicitly requiring that the mapped type in a `std::[unordered_]map` be an object type, however you would have to take great care to avoid `operator[]` which would attempt to default-construct the `value_type` which is `std::pair<int, FooPtr const &>`. For the unordered container, CopyAssignability of `value_type` is also required, for the sake of using dynamic arrays as hash buckets, and although references are CopyAssignable (the copy devolves to the referenced object), a pair containing a reference is not.

I doubt that the intent of the library is to allow references there, but the prohibition may be missing. Anyway, I'm sleepy right now. Perhaps someone can find it.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. So basically, my mistake was that I created an object that I owned (the smart pointer), but being a temporary -- "however you would have to take great care to avoid `operator[]` which would attempt to default-construct the `value_type`" - FYI, this map in the real code is a `static const`, so I won't be calling `operator[]` on it, only `::at()`. Can you suggest an alternative so that I can initialize my map with `unique_ptr`s?

Comment: @user3477950 For `initializer_list` based constructors, the standard requires the `value_type` be `EmplaceConstructible` from `*il.begin()`, which unfortunately simply isn't true for `pair<const int, unique_ptr<...>>`.

Comment: @T.C. Aham, so it's not possible then. :/ Thank you.

Comment: @user3477950 You can wrap a `unique_ptr` as a `mutable` member in a class with a moving converting constructor from `unique_ptr` and a moving implicit conversion back to `unique_ptr`. (Both types by value, not references.) Don't tell anyone I told you, it's a hack.

Comment: @Potatoswatter Thanks, but I'm not intending to fall back to hacks, even if the standard library is defective ;) I ended up using assignments to fill up the map.